# WCF Server - Crud Operations - separate methods and dont have one big file

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to write a WCF Server that handles CRUD Operation for my database, and I am kinda stuck in how to write the wcf server itself.

In alot of example I have an Interface like "IService1" where all the methods are stored, now I start wondering since I have like 50 tables in my database which I would like to CRUD over wcf is there a way to serparate the crud operations and dont have 50 times the methods

- GetXXXItem
- GetXXXItems
- UpdateXXXItem
- CreateXXXItem
- DeleteXXXItem

Which would result into 5 * 50 = 250 methods in a single Interface/class dont really like that idea.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: WCF is irrelevant, how would you do this via any implementation of a data access layer? You might pare it down with generic methods and UPSERT patterns.

Comment: @Crowcoder don't really think that WCF Server is irrelevant... since it seems like it forces me to write everything in 1 File. As an alternative you can take the MVVM approach where all those CRUD operations would be separated in different ViewModels with a base ViewModel. Which would result into 50 + 1 classes and basically my question is can I not separate those methods like in MVVM, am I really forced to write EVERYTHING in one HUGE file?!?

Comment: you don't need one file. You can implement as many service endpoints as you want.

Comment: @Crowcoder is right - it's not WCF specific. Isn't the same if you need to write DAL as db stored procedures? How about EF derived `DbContext` containing `DbSet` member for every database table?

Comment: @Crowcoder could you provide a link, since as I state in the question I have only found examples with 1 file alias "Service1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple services. Assuming you have a project generated from WCF Service template, you can right-click the project, Add New Item and select WCF Service (from the Visual C# list).
Do this for as many services you want to create.

[image]

[image]